xp_dirtree accessing shared folder with permission
I am trying to use xp_dirtree to get files from a shared folder, but the result returned is empty
I think it is because the shared folder is accessible only with username and password, but I could not find a way to set the credentials to this function
is there a way to archive this?
thanks
Andrea

Since this isn't related to the SQL language, I removed that tag. (Perhaps you could add  tag instead?)

You might get lucky if you give sql server (or cmdshell proxy) account access to the share, but i think this is usually a path of failure anyway. SQL Server is not a generic file management system. Why do you need to call xp_dirtree

We need to import the file info on a database, we used to have a folder on the same machine, so this way was pretty simple.
Now we also have to get file info from a shared and we got stucked in this issue, at this point I think we need to abandon the stored procedure and do it in a different way

Doesn't sound very simple. Why aren't you using Powershell or a batch file or some application? TSQL is not a generalized scripting language, don't abuse it as such.

I'd probably write a task scheduler script that write this info from the share server but maybe that has own problems
